# dateutil parser for month/year format: return beginning of month

Tags: python, regex, datetime, parsing

When I parse dates I use the `parser.parse` method that automatically recognizes all sorts of syntaxes from raw text. My problem arises when I have some strings  like "10/2018", with no day number information. The parser returns by default a datetime object at the last day of the month (here the 30th); i would like to change this behaviour so that it returns the first day of the month instead (ex: `datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0)`). How can I achieve this?

```
from dateutil import parser
mystring = ["10/2018", "05/10/2018", "Oct, 2018"]
[parser.parse(i) for i in mystring]
#### Out[5] [datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 30, 0, 0)]
```

Thanks,

Comment: The last day in October is the 31st, no?

Comment: @thebjorn yes Indeed, that's weird. For February it gets it right (28), but everyone else is at 30.. that could deserve a new question!

Comment: Figured it out (first code line in https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/parser/_parser.html#parser.parse).  It gives you the 30th because today is the 30th...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick look at the docs (https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) shows that `parse()` defaults to last of month unless a default datetime object is supplied:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

mystring = ["10/2018", "05/10/2018", "Oct, 2018"]
[parser.parse(i, default=datetime(1978, 1, 1, 0, 0)) for i in mystring]

# [datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: A few secs ahead of me :-) nice answer

Comment: you should provide the output of the last line. also, you don't need to specify the trailing zeros in the datetime constructor.

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly. I had not understood well this notion of "default datetime object" in the doc, thanks.

Comment: @thebjorn that may be true, but as this questions concerns specifying values vs accepting defaults, I figured specifying values was preferred.

Comment: Fair enough :-)